# Suddenly received 4 duplicate Announcer badges on 3 different sites

Tags: support

In the last couple of hours I have received 4 Announcer badges. Two of them on Super User, one on IT Security and another one on ServerFault.

This seems slightly abnormal to me because probability of 4 announcer badges suddenly being awarded within short period of time is rather small on my understanding.

I just double checked and found that all these badges are duplicates. I had been already awarded Announcer badges for those questions in the past.

Can somebody look into this?

Comment: I got a bunch of "share a link to a post" badge progress as well...

Comment: @MichaelFrank, yes those are called Announcer badges.

Comment: Oh, I didn't see those ones near the bottom of my notifications. >_>

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/339664/missing-publicist-badge Looks like they fixed a bug?

Comment: @MichaelFrank, Good find. I posted the answer with the link to that post.

Answer (score 1):

There is a [post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/340289) on Meta SE that covers this.

Briefly: There is an ongoing change in the logic of how `Announcer`, `Booster` and `Publicist` badges are awarded. As result, some users could receive duplicate badges which will be removed in next few days.